# Random selection of values in a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to use the values from column 'records_to_select' as 'k', in order to select the number of random values from column 'pnrTuple' (looking like this `(35784905, 40666303, 47603805, 68229102)` - a tuple). I need to do this for the whole dataframe. Basically if this is the value for 'pnrTuple' `(35784905, 40666303, 47603805, 68229102)` and this `3` is the value for 'records_to_select', I need to select randomly 3 of the id's. I'm open for any other ways to do this.
The code obviously is not working, I just want to show what i want to do.

```
mass_grouped3['pnrTuple'] = mass_grouped3['pnrTuple'].map(lambda x: random.choices(x, k=mass_grouped3['records_to_select']))



bula    gender  age hhgr    pnr freq    records_to_select   pnrTuple
1   1   1   3   ['35784905', '40666303', '47603805', '68229102']    4   4   ('35784905', '40666303', '47603805', '68229102')
1   1   2   1   ['06299501', '07694901', '35070201', '36765601', '97818801']    5   5   ('06299501', '07694901', '35070201', '36765601', '97818801')
1   1   2   2   ['17182402']    1   1   ('17182402',)
1   1   2   3   ['07992601', '20164401', '26817203', '50584001']    4   4   ('07992601', '20164401', '26817203', '50584001')
1   1   3   1   ['07935501', '08720401', '19604501', '26873301', '46069001', '65829601']    6   6   ('07935501', '08720401', '19604501', '26873301', '46069001', '65829601')
1   1   3   2   ['06529901', '21623801', '21624202', '31730001', '35448801', '36460001', '79142201', '98476701']    8   5   ('06529901', '21623801', '21624202', '31730001', '35448801', '36460001', '79142201', '98476701')
1   1   3   3   ['08786301', '17729602', '34827202', '35191802', '36106801', '41139001', '60815801', '65889401', '82642901', '89476501', '97523201', '98668501']    12  8   ('08786301', '17729602', '34827202', '35191802', '36106801', '41139001', '60815801', '65889401', '82642901', '89476501', '97523201', '98668501')
1   1   4   1   ['04282501', '07389801', '08988001', '13514901', '33755101', '36010101', '40009501', '46641001', '49795401', '51045401', '78502101', '84993601', '85047501']    13  9   ('04282501', '07389801', '08988001', '13514901', '33755101', '36010101', '40009501', '46641001', '49795401', '51045401', '78502101', '84993601', '85047501')
1   1   4   2   ['05250501', '17896401', '27035401', '32701701', '34741602', '42196402', '42891001', '67090301', '69240301', '77546701', '87855401', '96712602']    12  8   ('05250501', '17896401', '27035401', '32701701', '34741602', '42196402', '42891001', '67090301', '69240301', '77546701', '87855401', '96712602')
1   1   4   3   ['08047701', '08735402', '15113502', '16648302', '21618901', '26166801', '36508001', '40297801', '42864202', '47068001', '54051002', '68229104', '68555401', '76081901', '80639302', '86100502', '88471102', '98655102', '98672301']    19  13  ('08047701', '08735402', '15113502', '16648302', '21618901', '26166801', '36508001', '40297801', '42864202', '47068001', '54051002', '68229104', '68555401', '76081901', '80639302', '86100502', '88471102', '98655102', '98672301')
1   1   5   1   ['06027001', '14817601', '17035701', '26482001', '40580701', '41411301', '43383101', '50290201', '66963901', '98378101']    10  7   ('06027001', '14817601', '17035701', '26482001', '40580701', '41411301', '43383101', '50290201', '66963901', '98378101')
1   1   5   2   ['04215802', '04986702', '06021301', '07696001', '08310701', '09248301', '10429402', '13377101', '14652801', '14742402', '16179901', '19003801', '26296401', '30262201', '32109302', '42196401', '43343005', '69230101', '79169901', '81551801', '85026001', '88785201']    22  15  ('04215802', '04986702', '06021301', '07696001', '08310701', '09248301', '10429402', '13377101', '14652801', '14742402', '16179901', '19003801', '26296401', '30262201', '32109302', '42196401', '43343005', '69230101', '79169901', '81551801', '85026001', '88785201')
1   1   5   3   ['06208701', '10235601', '11200904', '26165901', '28133401', '30318101', '42304401', '48289402', '68324402', '79444601', '86214301', '89292601', '89644901', '95844702', '98833201']    15  10  ('06208701', '10235601', '11200904', '26165901', '28133401', '30318101', '42304401', '48289402', '68324402', '79444601', '86214301', '89292601', '89644901', '95844702', '98833201')
1   1   6   1   ['04076601', '04299501', '05992601', '06070001', '06749701', '10940601', '11880801', '13789901', '15641601', '15652201', '16359701', '17115201', '17944501', '27168601', '30034901', '40494901', '41876001', '43269501', '43443801', '65935901', '72038401', '76173101', '85624501', '85865301', '86858901', '88302301', '97266501']    27  19  ('04076601', '04299501', '05992601', '06070001', '06749701', '10940601', '11880801', '13789901', '15641601', '15652201', '16359701', '17115201', '17944501', '27168601', '30034901', '40494901', '41876001', '43269501', '43443801', '65935901', '72038401', '76173101', '85624501', '85865301', '86858901', '88302301', '97266501')
1   1   6   2   ['00305501', '00364401', '00467701', '06004101', '06760101', '13484301', '14101401', '14604101', '15296601', '16701801', '17295801', '19292501', '21692601', '22043401', '26117302', '30296102', '31566301', '32082501', '32975801', '33007502', '33901301', '36627901', '40933601', '40950801', '40953901', '41599201', '41647601', '42030702', '43249601', '43253601', '46177002', '46425001', '60285901', '62801802', '63203001', '63641601', '71358803', '72198201', '78789501', '79287901', '82297701', '85000802', '85458401', '86637402', '86755601', '87113101', '87312501', '87457701', '87617901', '96706301', '97494201', '97549601']    52  36  ('00305501', '00364401', '00467701', '06004101', '06760101', '13484301', '14101401', '14604101', '15296601', '16701801', '17295801', '19292501', '21692601', '22043401', '26117302', '30296102', '31566301', '32082501', '32975801', '33007502', '33901301', '36627901', '40933601', '40950801', '40953901', '41599201', '41647601', '42030702', '43249601', '43253601', '46177002', '46425001', '60285901', '62801802', '63203001', '63641601', '71358803', '72198201', '78789501', '79287901', '82297701', '85000802', '85458401', '86637402', '86755601', '87113101', '87312501', '87457701', '87617901', '96706301', '97494201', '97549601')
1   1   6   3   ['10368305', '17205801', '20164403', '26295901', '26817201', '40666302', '60751201', '89908101']    8   5   ('10368305', '17205801', '20164403', '26295901', '26817201', '40666302', '60751201', '89908101')
1   2   1   1   ['00854101']    1   1   ('00854101',)
```

Comment: Its helpful to create a small set of dummy data to emulate the issue you're running into so we can have code to play with.

Comment: @MattW. I edited the post. Sorry I dont know how to upload a file. You need the last two columns. 4 -  'records_to_select'  and   ('35784905', '40666303', '47603805', '68229102')  - pnrTuple

Comment: no worries. Take a look at my dummy dataframe. You can create a dataframe that way, or just hand-code a 3 row dataframe that has up to 4 values in each tuple, just to minimally illustrate your problem. You don't need to put your actual data up, you just need to show the issue you're getting with some small amount of data. even `df = pd.DataFrame({'tup':[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8)], 'records_to_select':[2, 4]})` would be enough to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets create a dummy dataframe first:

```
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':range(1, 101),
              'tups':[(random.randint(1, 1000000), random.randint(1, 1000000), random.randint(1, 1000000),
                       random.randint(1, 1000000), random.randint(1, 1000000), random.randint(1, 1000000)) for _ in range(100)],
              'records_to_select':[random.randint(1, 5) for _ in range(100)]})
```

Lets take a look at that dataframe:

```
df.head()

   id                                              tups  records_to_select
0   1    (59216, 532002, 799100, 829539, 968212, 62046)                  5
1   2  (217750, 448108, 333314, 417604, 330570, 991236)                  2
2   3   (352810, 242235, 466270, 169478, 155754, 29238)                  3
3   4   (309312, 867221, 304830, 278511, 547559, 72195)                  1
4   5   (872128, 556190, 112937, 33984, 759746, 549025)                  2
```

Here we have a `tups` column where we want to randomly select from, and then a `records_to_select` column where we have a number we want to sample.

The way I generally solve a problem is to do it once first. Here we just create a single tuple, and then figure out how to randomly sample from it. One way to do it is `random.sample(list, number)`. I had it return a tuple as well, though it returns a list by default:

```
x = (3, 7, 5, 0, 2, 8, 6, 1)
tuple(random.sample(x, 4))
(3, 0, 5, 8)
```

Now we can use `apply` along with `lambda` to iterate over the dataframe and apply it to every row.

```
df['samples_from_tuple'] = df.apply(lambda x: tuple(random.sample(x['tups'], x['records_to_select'])), axis=1)


df.head()

id  tups    records_to_select   samples_from_tuple
0   1   (476833, 384041, 789847, 233342, 527508, 892565)    4   (384041, 233342, 527508, 476833)
1   2   (759298, 654362, 244128, 851410, 233892, 612689)    2   (759298, 851410)
2   3   (640435, 391573, 290131, 277103, 250173, 756359)    2   (391573, 277103)
3   4   (788502, 128537, 560571, 42867, 47120, 71505)       1   (47120,)
4   5   (356955, 813874, 731805, 943841, 972449, 247512)    5   (356955, 972449, 813874, 731805, 247512)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you have a table as following:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"pnrTuple":[(1,2,3,4,5), (5,3,325,3463,7,23,46,4)], "records_to_select": [3, 5]})
>>> df
                                 a  b
0                  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  3
1  (5, 3, 325, 3463, 7, 23, 46, 4)  5
```

I believe the function `apply` would help:

```
>>> import random
>>> df.apply(lambda row: random.sample(row['pnrTuple'], row['records_to_select']), axis=1)
```